# Create a multivariate distribution with custom equation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have the following distribution,

**PDF[x] =** $\begin{cases}
 -\frac{3 \left(x^2-40 x+200 \log (x)+300-200 \log (10)\right)}{2000} & 0<x<10 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}$

I would like to construct a 4-dimensional distribution with 4 parameters (x1, x2, x3, x4) in which all the parameters have this distribution, and in addition they are correlated. So its basically a custom multivariate distribution with a non identity covariance matrix.

Any ideas in how to construct this distribution?

The idea is later to evaluate the PDF of a certain point (a,b,c,d).

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

What I want to build is similar to `MultiNormalDistribution` but instead of a Normal distribution I would like to use this custom PDF with a certain covariance matrix.

Comment: More specifics are needed and unless you're a Bayesian, parameters don't have distributions.  Where is the parameter in the example given?  Does each random variable have 4 parameters? What kind of dependence do you want for the 4 random variables?

Comment: @JimBaldwin As you noted this comes from a Bayesian analysis. So each parameter in my Bayesian analysis is a random variable and they're correlated. All 4 random variables have the same positive covariance of 0.104.

Comment: OK.  So X1, X2, X3, and X4 are parameters in a Bayesian framework with the same marginal distribution.  You mention "correlation" and a "covariance matrix" but those items are features of a joint probability density function.  It does not always follow that a specific non-identity covariance matrix will result in a unique multivariate density.  The `CopulaDistribution` function will construct such a multivariate probability density function but there are zillions of possible functions with the desired marginals.  How will you identify the one you want?

Comment: @JimBaldwin I'm a little bit confused. What I want to build is similar to `MultiNormalDistribution` but instead of a Normal distribution I would like to use this custom PDF with a certain covariance matrix.

Comment: Please see the references given by @gwr given below.  You'll also need to be more specific.  The marginal distribution above has mean 5/4 and variance 85/48.  And depending on the copula chosen, the conditional mean of say x2 given x1 is likely not linear so a correlation might not be easily or appropriately interpreted.  If you're wedded to selecting a correlation or covariance first, then you'll need to solve for the associated copula parameter.  Do you have a specific correlation or covariance in mind?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't always read so well.  I see from your first comment that you want a covariance of 0.104.  I'll adjust my answer to get that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [CopulaDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopulaDistribution.html) function to generate a multivariate distribution with a set of specified marginal distributions.

With your example (where the parameters are all set) if we have all marginal distributions being identical, you can use the following:

```
(* Marginal distribution *)
d = ProbabilityDistribution[-3 (x^2 - 40 x + 200 Log[x] + 300 - 200 Log[10])/2000, {x, 0, 10}];

(* Construct multivariate distribution *)
multivariateD = CopulaDistribution[{"Clayton", 1}, {d, d, d, d}];

(* Evaluate the multivariate density function at an arbitrary point *)
N[PDF[multivariateD, {1, 2, 3, 7}]]
(* 0.0000390693 *)
```

Please see the documentation for `CopulaDistribution` to see what kinds of dependence structures you can impose.

***Update***

If you want the covariance of any two of the random variables to be 0.104, then you can find the corresponding $c$ parameter of the "Clayton" kernel with

```
d = ProbabilityDistribution[-3 (x^2 - 40 x + 200 Log[x] + 300 - 200 Log[10])/2000,
      {x, 0, 10}];
μ = Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] d]
FindRoot[NIntegrate[(x1 - μ) (x2 - μ) PDF[CopulaDistribution[{"Clayton", c}, {d, d}], {x1, x2}],
  {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}] == 0.104, {c, 6.7}]
(* .... Lots of warning messages.... *)
(* {c -> 6.67695} *)
```

Comment: Some helpful intro to Copulas can be found on Stats.SE (e.g. [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37951/introductory-reading-on-copulas)).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!